# AutoIt Info unable to show ID elemnet of calculator in windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-10, autoit-c#-wrapper

```
    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.run("calc.exe");
    x.winActivate("Calculator");
    x.winWaitActive("Calculator");
    //Enter 3
    x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "201. 396") ;
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    //Enter +
    x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "35") ;
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    //Enter 3
    x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "201. 396") ;
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    //Enter =
    x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "276") ;
```

Same code is running in Windows 7. AutoIt Recorder is also not working. What to do in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
; Win 7

; Run the Windows Calculator.
Run("calc.exe")

; Wait for the calculator to become active with a timeout of 10 seconds.
WinWaitActive("[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", 10)

; If the calculator did not appear after 10 seconds then exit the script.
If WinExists("[CLASS:CalcFrame]") = 0 Then Exit

; Automatically type the 123456789 into the calculator.
ControlSend("[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "","[CLASS:#32770; INSTANCE:1]", '123456789')

; Slow the script down so we can see what's going on.
Sleep(6000)

; Close the Windows calculator - always tidy up afterwards.
WinClose("[CLASS:CalcFrame]")

; win10

; Run the Windows Calculator.
Run("calc.exe")

; Wait for the calculator to become active with a timeout of 10 seconds.
WinWaitActive("[CLASS:ApplicationFrameWindow]", "", 10)

; If the calculator did not appear after 10 seconds then exit the script.
If WinExists("[CLASS:ApplicationFrameWindow]") = 0 Then Exit

; Automatically type the 123456789 into the calculator.
ControlSend("[CLASS:ApplicationFrameWindow]", "","Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow1", '123456789')

; Slow the script down so we can see what's going on.
Sleep(6000)

; Close the Windows calculator - always tidy up afterwards.
WinClose("[CLASS:ApplicationFrameWindow]")
```

Comment: Use the Autoit Window Info Tool to have a look whether the ID has changed, And of course for Win10, you have to use this class. [CLASS:ApplicationFrameWindow] So try using: ControlClick("[CLASS:ApplicationFrameWindow] ",'', $iCalcPlus)

Comment: AutoIT window Info Tool is not recognising. That is the major issue for me.